# My data model doesn't fit with a selection of rows in 2 columns

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, .net-core

I’m quite new on Entity Framework Core (more exactly `Npgsql.EFCore.PostgresSQL` 5.0.0)  and I need your help.

I want to select some data in a table according to a list of Ids and I want also data from another columns in the table which describe here a geometry in bytes. In other words, my selection will returns 2 columns. Moreover, the response must keep the same order of my list of Ids.

For the moment, I use this raw SQL:

```
String rawRequest = "SELECT Ids, ST_AsBinary(geom_wkb) as geom_wkb" +
                    "FROM {SCHEMA}.{Table}"  +
                    "JOIN UNNEST(ARRAY["+ {List_of_Ids_To_retrieve +"]::bigint[]) "+
                    "WITH ORDINALITY route(Ids, ordering) USING(Ids)";
```

Finally I call this

```
var response =  context.wkbObject
              .FromSqlRaw(rawRequest);
```

Knowing my data model is :

```
[Table("one_table")]
public class wkbObject
{
    [Column("Ids")]
    [Key]
    public long[] Ids { get; set; }
    [Column ("geom_wkb ")]
    public byte[] geom_wkb { get; set; }
}
```

When I want to do a loop over the response

```
foreach (var wkb in response)
{
     /// Do stuff on the geom.. 
}
```

It seems the compiler shut down at the clause “in” and it seems the data model doesn’t fit. I got this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Can't cast database type bigint to Int64[]

Why?

My questions are:

- Why it doesn't work :
- Where does my type conversion problem come from?
- Is my data model is correct ? I don’t know very well if when I select several rows in a columns if I need a list (or not) in the data model? Writing this I realized I have an array of long for Ids but I have a simple array of bytes (Need I a list of array of Bytes?).
- How is the data structure of the response ? Need I use the ToList() function ?
- My request could be written with Link? Is it better?
- Is it possible to do that in an asynchronous way ?

Comment: This is a consulting not a free coding service. One question in a time. Plus read this before asking https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

When I clicked to send my question I understand where is the conversion error. In my data model I change `long[]` to `long` and it works.

But I still need your help. Is it better to use Linq ? How do that in asynchronous way ?
 `var response =  await context.wkbObject.FromSqlRaw(rawRequest2);` doesn't work

Comment: Here there's a good reason to use raw SQL, and for async it's `await context.wkbObject.FromSqlRaw(rawRequest2).ToListAsync()`